# Play a sound every N milliseconds

Tags: java, android, audio

I'm developing a metronome application. The user can select at runtime the bpm, and my app will play the "tick" sound accordingly. The "tick" is a single metronome "shot" (mp3). I tried implementing it using Handler and MediaPlayer, but the metronome is not precise at all.
So I thought about changing the whole approach: when the user choose a new bpm value, I synthesize a new sound by repeating the tick sound X times every N milliseconds, then looping over this runtime created sound.
Is this a valid alternative? How can it be implemented in Android?

Comment: Looping will, again, create an inaccurate delay. So you need to use a long metronome sound, the longest the better, to avoid or, at least, minimize the delay between plays in the loop. And, then, use some method to cope with the introduced delay, by comparing the current time with the running time and advancing forward the playing stream to compensate the offset.

Comment: Actually, I implemented this through AudioTrack and the looping delay you are talking about is not noticeable at all. Compared with a real metronome, it's about 0.5 bpm so it's definetly acceptable

Comment: Can you maybe show me some code how you've done this? I'm actually quite interested!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The alternative of looping through a synthesized sound seems to be the best choice for now. There was a *great* session about audio on Google I/O 2013 called [High Performance Audio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=d3kfEeMZ65c) that I would certainly advice watching for having a deeper understanding on how the system works and what problems the developers will face when dealing with the audio latency. At about the 17:00 of the video, there is graph that shows [jitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jitter) versus callbacks. In the perfect world that does not exist (oh really?), the jitter would be zero for all the scheduled audio callbacks made. But that is not the case, for there are jitters as high as 35 milliseconds or even greater, for the data in the graph was made using an unspecified ICS device and there are certainly worse scenarios than that.

So, as a metronome is a precision tool and these jitters are not good at all, the scheduled playback approach should be left aside. I even made an reasonably realiable metronome work with a synthesized sound using `AudioTrack`.

Hope it helps ^^

Comment: Sorry if this is late, bit could you please post your code where you successfully implemented a metronome using `AudioTrack`?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) scheduled for **fixed-rate** execution on a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html).

Timer and TimerTask are both part of the Android SDK (and Java SE). The executions do not delay because of execution time of the previous event.

```
Timer timer = new Timer("MetronomeTimer", true);
TimerTask tone = new TimerTask(){
     @Override
     public void run(){
         //Play sound
     }
};
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tone, 500, 500); //120 BPM. Executes every 500 ms.
```

You can then cancel the TimerTask when you need to change the BPM.

```
tone.cancel();
tone = new TimerTask(){...}
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tone, 1000, 1000); //60 BPM. Executes every 1000 ms.
```

Another possibility that may meet your requirements (from your comments) is spinning a thread and checking System.nanoTime() and sleeping in increments but spinning when you get close to wake up.

```
long delayNanos = 500000000;
long wakeup = System.nanoTime() + delayNanos; //Half second from right now
long now;

while(!done){
     now = System.nanoTime();

     //If we are less than 50 milliseconds from wake up. Spin away. 
     if(now <= wakeup - 50000000){
          //Sleep in very small increments, so we don't spin unrestricted.

          Thread.sleep(10); 
     }
     if(now >= wakeup){
           //Play sound
           wakeup += delayNanos;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thread implementations are not good for this task, both in the Java flavor (Timer+TimerTask) and in the Android one (Handler+Message). The timing on mobiles is absolutely bad

Comment: To avoid the granularity issue with regard to waits, there's the possibility of a thread that keeps going around (using Thread.yield()), checking the time constantly, and waking up the other thread. Might be a solution.

Comment: @Raffaele Added to my answer with a more appropriate solution.

Comment: @Dev Already tried :) Playing sound is remarkably irregular, and depends on user frequency and CPU load. That's way I'm convinced that the threaded approach is not adequate in this situation

Comment: @Raffaele Even if the logic had no sleep and was single threaded it would still be irregular?

Comment: Do you mean kinda while(true) {if we are close enough playsound else continue} ? I think it may work, but what about CPU usage? We are on a mobile platform with a battery. Do you think an infinite loop is a suitable way?

Comment: @Raffaele You could add in sleeps if you are far enough away from the time to play the sound, but you'll want the thread awake and spinning when you get close (like 50ms or so). This is what I ment by the //Play sound comment in my code example. You should play the sound from that thread not wake up another one.

Comment: @Raffaele On second thought, you may not even need to sleep. While the metronome is active I think it would be acceptable to use a spinning thread.

Comment: Anyway, as I said, I already tried it [link](http://pastebin.com/mTebw6Eg) but the problem with precision still stays (You can see, in the paste, I changed the value of delay to simulate a higher bpm. You can paste that code into an empty Activity and see what happens)

Answer (score 0):

When this play sound is called

```
mSoundManager.playSound(1);
```

Android waits until that call is finished, then you call

```
mHandler.postAtTime(this, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 200);
```

however, if you reverse those calls, you may find that the timing is more accurate.

```
mHandler.postAtTime(this, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 200);
mSoundManager.playSound(1);
```

You can't count on your sound taking exactly the same amount of time to play, so telling the handler to post first is a bit better. Still not ideal, however.