# Precise metronome for android

Tags: java, android

The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018824/play-a-sound-every-n-milliseconds) states that we can make a reliable and precise metronome on Android using `AudioTrack`. We can use `MediaPlayer`, `SoundPool`, `Thread` and `Timer` as well, but they are always causing a delay. Instead of generating a synthesized sound using `AudioTrack`, how can we achieve the same effect using custom audio files?

Answer (score 4):

You can try to create your own time counter using `System.nanoTime()`, when you need precision, you always can use this.

> `public static long nanoTime()`
>
> Returns the current value of the most
>   precise available system timer, in nanoseconds. This method can only
>   be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion
>   of system or wall-clock time. The value returned represents
>   nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary time (perhaps in the
>   future, so values may be negative). This method provides nanosecond
>   precision, but not necessarily nanosecond accuracy. No guarantees are
>   made about how frequently values change. Differences in successive
>   calls that span greater than approximately 292 years (263 nanoseconds)
>   will not accurately compute elapsed time due to numerical overflow.
>
> For example, to measure how long some code takes to execute:
>
> long startTime = System.nanoTime();    // ... the code being
>   measured ...    long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
>   Returns: The current value of the system timer, in nanoseconds. Since:
>   1.5

Source:

Oracle Documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()