# Play sound precisely every one second

Tags: android, performance, audio

I am learning to code for Android and I have a problem with... maybe performance?
I want to play very short sound every second. I have created a CountDownTimer (with tick interval 20ms so very accurate) and putted there in onTick to play it. But the sound is played not precisely after one second and I can hear this - this is the problem...

fragment of my code:

```
private class ExerciseCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer
{
...
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
{
    ...
    if(/*this is a next second not just a tick*/)
        playSound(R.raw.quick_rest, true);
}
}

private void playSound(int resId, boolean releaseAfter)
{
    if (currentMediaPlayerRes != resId || mediaPlayer == null)
    {
        if (mediaPlayer != null)
        {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
        currentMediaPlayerRes = resId;
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
        if (releaseAfter)
        {
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
                {
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    mediaPlayer = null;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Is it possible to have counter like this?

Comment: Maybe this post will help you find what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018824/play-a-sound-every-n-milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

use this code to play a music one time

```
 MediaPlayer AlarmMusic;
 AlarmMusic = MediaPlayer.create(G.context, R.raw.music1);
 AlarmMusic.setLooping(false);
 AlarmMusic.start();
```

this worked for me !

Comment: Actually I can play a sound even multiple times. The problem is that the sound is not played precisely every second. I can hear that sometimes it is earlier and sometimes it is later.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the lack of real time guarantees in Java/Android, using one thread to cue another probably will always have some inaccuracy.

I can think of two approaches that might work for you:

(1) make the sound file exactly 1 second long, e.g., 44100 frames at 44100 fps, if you are using the standard "CD-quality" format that Java supports. The sound file can probably be edited with Audacity to an exact frame length. Then, use a looping playback.

(2) Open a line for streaming audio. I can't recall exactly what the Android-supported command is for this, but I know it exists. With it, count elapsing frames while sending silence (bytes with 0 value). When you get to the 44100th frame, start feeding the PCM data that you wish to hear. When it is done, go back to feeding 0's until the next 44100 frame arrives. Never stop the line--keep it running in its own thread, probably with a high priority. It is generally okay to give audio a high priority (as long as you are doing nothing else on the line) as audio spends a vast majority of its time in a "blocked" state during which it is yielding to other lines.

A fellow on java-gaming.org made a metronome and got it working on Android. I bet if you search for "metronome" on that site, his thread will pop up and have some useful info. He basically used the second approach that I described above.

Comment: Hmm good and quite easy with point 1. I will try this and mark your post as an answer after checking if this will work. If not then maybe point 2 but sounds a bit complicated.

Comment: Looping did not help. It took some time between next loop and I think it was in precise spaces but I do not want to belong on this because probably this spaces can differ on different devices...
If I have a time I will try this second option.

Comment: What command are you using for the looping? I'd like to look at the api for it. I thought of a third possibility: take that file you made (assuming it is exactly the right number of frames) and make it the source data for the Android command for streaming audio: every time you get to the last byte, restarting. Then, you don't have to count the elapsing frames or manage when to send 0's instead of the file itself.