# Advice for repeating the code for after millisecond delays in Java

Tags: java

I have an usecase where I need to repeat the code (calling DB) after milliseconds until the condition is met.
I was looking the for loop with thread.sleep() and scheduled executor service in Java and I came across some questions.
Option 1: for loop + thread.sleep()

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {    
        helloWorld();
    }

    private static void helloWorld() throws InterruptedException {
        // CALL DB and do some logic
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Option 2: scheduled executor

```
Runnable helloRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // CALL DB and do some logic
    }
};

ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(helloRunnable, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

From I learned, both thread.sleep() + for loop and scheduled executor could serve the purpose of repeating the code after certain period of time.
Given that my usecase is only millisecond, what would be recommended approach between these two options.
Wouldn't there be more context switching and overhead in scheduled executor compared to simple for loop + thread.sleep() approach?
I saw some other threads that generally use of scheduled executor is preferred since it comes with a complete library. But what is the caveat of using it?
Thanks!

I am still exploring the options, so I need some advice or pointer.

Comment: Why would you design your own scheduling mechanism when Java specifically provides one?

Comment: The context switching overhead is much smaller than your delay.

Comment: Since it is a simple repeating code block for every millliseconds, I wanted to know if using scheduled executor is a overkill. @shmosel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Play a sound every N milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018824/play-a-sound-every-n-milliseconds)

Answer (score 0):

### `ScheduledExecutorService`

> until the condition

Your `executor.scheduleAtFixedRate` solution does not fit the problem. That command runs continually, without regard for a stop condition.

Instead, use a `ScheduledExecutorService` but pass a reference to the executor service to your task. The task then tests for the stop condition. If the condition indicates another run, the task schedules itself for another run.

Here is a complete example app.

We use `AtomicBoolean` as the condition flag indicating whether to continue scheduling further executions. In your scenario, the decision to continue or not would be based on the task’s results from the database query.

Notice here how we pass a reference to the `ScheduledExecutorService` to the constructor of the `Runnable` task. That object keeps a reference to that object in a `final` member variable. That executor service is used repeatedly, when the task reschedules itself for another execution.

```java
package work.basil.example.threading;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class RunUntil
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        RunUntil app = new RunUntil ( );
        app.demo ( );
    }

    public void demo ( )
    {
        System.out.println ( "Demo start at " + Instant.now ( ) );

        AtomicBoolean continueFlag = new AtomicBoolean ( true );
        ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor ( );
        Task task = new Task ( ses , Duration.ofMillis ( 333 ) , continueFlag );
        ses.submit ( task );
        // Wait a while for the task to do its thing for a few repetitions.
        try { Thread.sleep ( Duration.ofSeconds ( 1 ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException ( e ); }
        continueFlag.set ( false );
        this.shutdownAndAwaitTermination ( ses );

        System.out.println ( "Demo end at " + Instant.now ( ) );
    }

    // My slightly modified version of boilerplate taken from Javadoc of `ExecutorService`.
    void shutdownAndAwaitTermination ( ExecutorService executorService )
    {
        executorService.shutdown ( ); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
        try
        {
            // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
            if ( !executorService.awaitTermination ( 60 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) )
            {
                executorService.shutdownNow ( ); // Cancel currently executing tasks
                // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
                if ( !executorService.awaitTermination ( 60 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) )
                    System.err.println ( "Executor service did not terminate" );
            }
        } catch ( InterruptedException ex )
        {
            // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
            executorService.shutdownNow ( );
            // Preserve interrupt status
            Thread.currentThread ( ).interrupt ( );
        }
    }
}

class Task implements Runnable
{
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;
    private final Duration delay;
    final AtomicBoolean continueFlag;

    public Task ( ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService , Duration delay , AtomicBoolean continueFlag )
    {
        this.scheduledExecutorService = scheduledExecutorService;
        this.delay = delay;
        this.continueFlag = continueFlag;
    }

    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {
        System.out.println ( "At the tone, the time will be: " + LocalTime.now ( ) );
        if ( this.continueFlag.get ( ) )
        {
            this.scheduledExecutorService.schedule ( this , this.delay.toNanos ( ) , TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS );
        }
    }
}
```

When run:

```
Demo start at 2023-12-28T04:11:22.819976Z
At the tone, the time will be: 20:11:22.837084
At the tone, the time will be: 20:11:23.173556
At the tone, the time will be: 20:11:23.508041
At the tone, the time will be: 20:11:23.843963
Demo end at 2023-12-28T04:11:23.844279Z
```

### Sleeping

How does the `ScheduledExecutorService` approach compare to just using `Thread.sleep` in a loop?

The `Thread.sleep` approach is certainly much shorter and simpler. But in that approach your original thread is asleep, blocked, unable to perform any other work.

With the `ScheduledExecutorService` approach, the original thread can perform other work while the task runs in a background thread managed by the executor service.